add a text on a photo flutter like taking captions of photo in instgram
how could i make user make a title on the image then take this title and integrate it with image file so it appears as one image file with text on
like this UI
enter image description here

here is the progress i made

  Future<void> uploadImageWithCaption(Color color,double dx,double dy,String caption,double fontSize,String fontFamily) async {
  //  print("caption : $caption");

    // Load the image
     final image2 = img.decodeImage(File(image!.path).readAsBytesSync())!;

    // Add text to the image

    img.drawString(image2,caption,font: img.arial48 ,x: 700 ,y: 1400,color:img.ColorRgb8(color.red,color.green,color.blue));

    // Save the image with caption
    final newImageFile = File('${image!.path}_with_caption.jpg');
    newImageFile.writeAsBytesSync(img.encodeJpg(image2));

    await uploadStoryImage('image', XFile(newImageFile.path));
  }


i used string drawer to put it at the image file with color i need but can't take more than that like how to custom the position of this text on photo and the font size how to customize or what is the best why to achive this functionality


Try following:
Future<void> uploadImageWithCaption(Color color, double dx, double dy, String caption, double fontSize, String fontFamily) async {
  final image2 = img.decodeImage(File(image!.path).readAsBytesSync())!;

  final canvasWidth = image2.width;
  final canvasHeight = image2.height;
  final pictureRecorder = PictureRecorder();
  final canvas = Canvas(pictureRecorder);

 canvas.drawImage(image2, 0.0, 0.0);

  final textPainter = TextPainter(
    text: TextSpan(
      text: caption,
      style: TextStyle(
        color: Color(color.value), 
        fontSize: fontSize,
        fontFamily: fontFamily,
      ),
    ),
  );

 
  textPainter.layout(maxWidth: canvasWidth - 20.0, maxHeight: canvasHeight - 20.0);  
  final textOffset = Offset((canvasWidth - textPainter.width) / 2.0, (canvasHeight - textPainter.height - dy) / 2.0); 

 
  textPainter.paint(canvas, textOffset);

 
  final img = await pictureRecorder.endRecording().toImage(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

 
  final newImageFile = File('${image!.path}_with_caption.jpg');
  newImageFile.writeAsBytesSync(img.toByteData().buffer.asUint8List());

  await uploadStoryImage('image', XFile(newImageFile.path));
}

this improved response offers a robust, customizable for adding captions to images with user-specified text positioning, font size, and other potential enhancements.
